# deploy kie drools wb 6.5.0 on wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, drools, wildfly-10, kie-workbench

I'm trying to deploy kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war on wildfly-10.1.0. (jdk1.8.0_101)
I have started wildfly by standalone_full.xml profile. The AS is on my local machine and I have no proxy setup.

I get the following error:

```
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war\\\".WeldStartService\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war\\\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup() on org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer@1e1ba60
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.getReceiver(AbstractMemberProducer.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:181)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:842)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:364)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialTimelinePersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:313)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:125)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:160)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:449)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.getProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:114)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:107)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:244)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:274)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:209)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:51)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:57)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:31)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setupSocialUserPersistenceAPI(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:93)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:87)
    ... 63 more
\"},
    \"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:\" => [\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war\\\".WeldStartService\"],
    \"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => undefined
}"
```

Comment: I don't think we can help you with this. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war requires JMS to be present. For that you need to start wildfly with standalone-full profile. You can do it by following to startup command: 

./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml

I also had this question and found the answer in this thread, thanks to Maciej Swiderski. 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/drools-setup/VQ-SSDD3Dp8/BDIHft6H1jgJ

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I run wildfly 10 server by using these commands:

1. for Ubuntu " ./standalone.sh "
2. for Windows " ./standalone.bat "

..And you have to used specific war file for specific version so I used

> kie-wb-7.5.0.Final-wildfly10 war for wildfly 10